How to Calculate the Spectral Intensity per Solid Angle in a Tungsten Bulb - Photodetector Setup
I have a setup with a tungsten bulb. The bulb has a 2cm diameter aperture in front of it. When the bulb is turned on, light from it hits a bi-convex lens 21.5cm away which then focuses the light onto a photodetector placed at the lens' focal length (10cm). The photodetector has an aperture of diameter 9mm
I want to take the spectral intensity at the photodetector and scale it to a directional spectral intensity at the bulb aperture (i.e. per unit solid angle). How do I calculate the solid angle of light hitting the photodetector, given that the lens in the setup is focussing light onto the detector.
Do I treat all light hitting the lens as also hitting the photodetector and, hence, take the solid angle to only be that at the lens aperture?
Or do I need to consider the solid angle at the photodetector aperture alone, ignoring the lens?
Please let me know how I can calculate the solid angle over which the intensity from the bulb is spread at the photodetector aperture.
